# joomla 1.5 component example

Tags: joomla, components, joomla1.5

I've written a few joomla components but feel like I could write them better and more efficient. I was hoping someone can recommend me an example I can download which follows mvc and is written well .and I'm not talking hello world, something with many features. joomla 1.5 only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

com_weblinks in default Joomla! 1.5 installation is the only component which is fully written with Joomla 1.5 MVC.
I suggest you to look at it when you're writing a new component - that's what i do.

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!!!! Awesome! I learned so many new things studying this one component!!!

Comment: Writing any new components, I am definitely starting with this one!

Comment: I'm glad i could help, have fun exploring Joomla! :)

Comment: Do you know if weblinks is the component I should follow for Joomla 1.7?

Comment: Im not sure bout Joomla 1.7, I'm still developing on 1.5 and waiting for 2.5 to be released, coz Joomla 1.7 will be unsupported in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the tutorial at joomla docs? I know it's a "helloworld" example, but it shows how to implement a model using the database, the controller, and the view. I think it's a good point to start.
[http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aDeveloping_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1)

Comment: Utes I've followed and its just for beginners. I was looking for something more complex. Thanks.